# SQL select statement in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, where-clause

Hi there I am trying to execute a query but cannot seem to get it right.

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  id IN (SELECT *
              FROM   table
              WHERE  description = 'A')
AND description = 'B'
```

Above is the query that I have got, the `select * from table where description = A` works as expected when ran alone I just need to make the where clause to work so I can see any id that has a description of A and B.

Comment: The description cannot both 'A' and 'B'. Just 'A' OR 'B'.

Comment: The thing is there may be multiple records of the same id, and they could contain a description of A or B, so the nested select statement finds only id's with a description of A, then I want to take those id's and find how many of them also have a description of B too. I think @SimonPJ solution should do this for me?

Comment: OK, I got it. I though the id is unique. @SimonPJ solution is the right answer, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be getting multiple columns from the sub query when I assume you only want the id column:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id
          FROM   table
          WHERE  description = 'A')
   AND description = 'B'
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I am after! Thanks a mil

Answer (score 2):

No need for the select in the where clause

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN ('A', 'B')
```

Comment: I think, OP's query will fetch `id` which are mapped to both 'A' and 'B'. but in your case it will fetch ids which are mapped to either 'A' or 'B'. the thing wrong in that query is `select *` in subquery.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE description IN ('A', 'B')
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
select * from table where id in (select id from table where description = 'A') and description = 'B'
```

but this query will give you zero result as you select records with description = 'A' and description = 'B', if you want to get records with either description of A or B, then you should write as

```
select * from table where description = 'A' or description = 'B'
```

or

```
select * from table where description in ('A','B')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct AnaTablo.Id , AnaTablo.FirmaAdi , AnaTablo.FirmaId , AnaTablo.KayitTarihi ,
users.Email Personel,   (SELECT top 1 sabitler.Ayar from tblSabitAyarlar sabitler WHERE sabitler.Tur = 29 and sabitler.Deger in 
(SELECT top 1 IslemId from tblEFaturaTakipIslem Islem WHERE AnaTablo.Id = Islem.EFaturaTakipId order by KayitTarihi desc))YapilanIslem,
AnaTablo.Eposta , AnaTablo.Aciklama
from tblEFaturaTakip AnaTablo left join AspNetUsers users on AnaTablo.PersonelId  = users.Id
```