# Getting specific row based on some keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get  specific row data based on the given ID.
Each Id have multiple rows in it.
So below is my example.

If I gave an ID in parameter for a query, I need to get the row where I have the names as Astika LLC  .

Below is my sample data.

```
ID        Place          Name               Description              Count
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7718    | UK1   |  Lemuis           | ERIS TELECOM  UK       | 0
7718     | UK1   |  Astika LLC       | VERIDIAN UK              | 34
7718    | UK1   |  Angel Telecom AG | VIACLOUD UK             | 34
7718    | UK1   |  DDC S.r.L        | ALPHA UK              | 25
7718    | UK1   |  Customers        | WERTS  UK               | 0
```

Here If I gave Id as 7718 I need to get second row only.

Comment: *"Here If I gave Id as 7718 I need to get second row only"* Why the second row specifically, (or why specifically the row containing `''Astika LLC'`)? Is it always the "second" row? What determines that the row containing `'Astika LLC'` is the "second" row; as I see no way to determine that it is the "second" row? What have *you* tried so far?

Comment: why don't you use the where clause, where name = 'Astika LLC'

Comment: Hey @Larnu not the second row.I need to get the row where I have Name value as Astika LLC .Actually Its a sample data.

Comment: @RedDevil if I use where I will get all the rows because every ID has multiple rows.

Comment: @Krish check my answer. It will return only 1 row

Comment: *"I need to get the row where I have Name value as Astika LLC"* So what dioes that have to do with supplying a value of `7718` for the column `ID`? You wouldn't walk into a DIY store to buy blue paint, and just state "I want the Dulux"; you'd be specific.Dulux is a brand, but it has nothing to do with that you want Blue Paint; saying "I want 7718" when you want Astika LLC is basically doing the same things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select statement in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234247/sql-select-statement-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from tablename 
where ID= 7718 and name = 'Astika LLC'
```

This will return only 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below query -

```
select * from tablename where name = 'Astika LLC'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this below code with your data?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY MyColumnToOrderBy) AS RowNum,
            *
        FROM
            Table_1
    ) sub
WHERE
    RowNum = 2
```

With the above code, you can get the nth row of the table.

if you need specific results, you can try this code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <tablename>
WHERE ID= 7718 AND Name = 'Astika LLC'
```